# How to build a newer version of a package than is available for my stable release?

Tags: compiling, packaging

I want to use a newer package version with my stable Ubuntu release. Asking for backport takes too long without visible result, so I thought that maybe I can build newer version myself.

Can anybody tell me what is the current best practices to build newer versions of packages that are already available on Ubuntu?

**UPDATE**: I found out that I need `pbuilder` to keep my system clean from build dependencies. So I've done:

```
sudo apt-get install pbuilder
sudo pbuilder create           # create isolated environment for building packages
```

**UPD2**: I tried to check if I can build current version, so I fetched source code for the current `<version>` of my `<package>`:

```
mkdir delme
cd delme
apt-get source <package>
```

**UPD3**: Now I tried build package from source, but can not find the results:

```
sudo pbuilder build *.dsc
```

The log says:

```
...
0 packages upgraded, 94 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 30.2 MB of archives. After unpacking 89.4 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 pbuilder-satisfydepends-dummy : Depends: libjansson-dev which is a virtual package.
                                 Depends: libudev-dev but it is not going to be installed.
                                 Depends: ocl-icd-opencl-dev which is a virtual package. or
                                          opencl-dev which is a virtual package.
Unable to resolve dependencies!  Giving up...
The following NEW packages will be installed:
...
Need to get 30.2 MB of archives. After unpacking 89.4 MB will be used.
Abort.
E: pbuilder-satisfydepends failed.
I: Copying back the cached apt archive contents
...
```

**UPD4**: It appeared that these unmet dependencies are from `universe` package repository, so I had to enable it:

```
sudo pbuilder update --components "main universe" --override-config
```

Without `--override-config` `pbuilder` will complain that it is not set. Everything is built successfully:

```
ls -la /var/cache/pbuilder/result/
```

**UP5**: Found out which package versions are available and fetched the source for the needed one:

```
uscan --report --verbose
uscan --download-version <version>
```

**UP6**: Found `uupdate` utility and used that to create directory for new package and update `debian/changelog`, which is needed to produce new version:

```
cd <package>-<old-version>
uupdate ../<package>_<version>.orig.tar.gz
cd ../<package>-<version>
vim debian/changelog
```

**UP7**: To build source with `pbuilder` I need to generate `.dsc` file. It is usually done with `debuild -S` command, or with `pdebuild -S` in `pbuilder.

```
pdebuild -S
```

This errors out:

```
...
 fakeroot debian/rules clean
dh clean --with autoreconf
dh: unable to load addon autoreconf: ..
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at (eval 19) line 2.

make: *** [clean] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: fakeroot debian/rules clean gave error exit status 2
```

Looks like there is no autoreconf package, but `pbiulder` is supposed to fetch it automatically, and seems like it uses `.dsc` file to do so. catch22.

**UPD8**: The command to build `.dsc` file is `dpkg-source`.

```
cd ..
dpkg-source -b <package>-<version>
```

Now it is possible to run `pbuilder` over it.

```
sudo pbuilder build <package>_<version>.dsc
ls -la /var/cache/pbuilder/result/
```

**UP9**: Uploading to PPA is as simple as running:

```
dput ppa:techtonik/backports /var/cache/pbuilder/result/<package>_<version>.changes
```

But it doesn't work:

```
Checking signature on .changes
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: the signature could not be verified.
...
No signature on /var/cache/pbuilder/result/<package>_<version>.changes
```

**UP10**: I don't remember how did I generated GPG key, but I have one. Found a way to sign the packages. Edited `Maintaner:` field in `.dsc` file and used `debsign`.

```
sudo vim /var/cache/pbuilder/result/<package>_<version>.dsc
sudo debsign /var/cache/pbuilder/result/<package>_<version>.changes
```

Attempt to upload failed:

```
Error: uploading files for distribution UNRELEASED to ppa not allowed.
```

**UP11**: Redone everything from step 6. How could I know that I need to edit `debian/changes` to replace `UNRELEASED` with `saucy` and set my email in `Maintainer:` field of `debian/control`?

```
vim <package>-<version>/debian/changelog
vim <package>-<version>/debian/control
dpkg-source -b <package>-<version>
sudo pbuilder build <package>_<version>.dsc
sudo debsign /var/cache/pbuilder/result/<package>_<version>.changes
sudo dput ppa:techtonik/backports /var/cache/pbuilder/result/<package>_<version>.changes
```

**UPD12**: I still can't upload to PPA. First it was `Unable to find distroseries: unstable`, because I specified `unstable` instead of `saucy` as `UNRELEASED` replacement. After repeated step 11 it complained with `Already uploaded to ...` which was healed with `-f` key to `dput`. Now there is a mail that upload is rejected, because `Source/binary (i.e. mixed) uploads are not allowed.`

Somewhere on the new it is said that I needed to build my package with `debuild -S`, but I don't know how to tell that to `pbuilder`.

**UPD14**: It appeared that the culprit is `dh-autoreconf` package, which is required for the cleaning source before the build, but both `pbuilder` and `debuild` miss this fact and unable to recover. Installing `dh-autoreconf` on the host system allowed to build source package, sign and upload it even without `pbuilder` build.

```
cd <package>-<version>
debuild -S
cd ..
dput ppa:techtonik/backports <package>_<version>_source.changes
```

Done.

Comment: What package are you trying to get the newest version of? Why not just download the source files and `./configure && make && make install` or if they are in the repositories just `sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install package_name`

Comment: @jmunsch, I am not sure what build dependencies are required, I'd prefer to keep my system clean of them, and no, versions are not in repositories.

Comment: The issue with the building, the lack of `dh-autoreconf` was identified in their [duplicate thread here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/396301/how-to-build-source-package-with-pbuilder-for-ppa-upload).  I would suggest marking this as a duplicate of that one, so that we can show that the issue has been identified (per comments on my answer on that other thread).

Comment: I am still looking for way to do a build in isolated environment. This is still not answered.

Comment: I can't help without package you intended to build.

Comment: @Gasol I intentionally left out the details about the package so that the answer could be useful for any package. As you see this post is a lot of pain and hacking. But I believe I was trying to get OpenCL working for my BOINC https://askubuntu.com/questions/576338/why-opencl-is-not-default-14-04-nvidia-331