# How to build source package with `pbuilder` for PPA upload?

Tags: ppa, packaging, pbuilder

I am trying to use `pbuilder` to upload to PPA. Package builds ok with the command:

```
sudo pbuilder build <package>_<version>.dsc
```

But upload fails with error:

```
Source/binary (i.e. mixed) uploads are not allowed.
```

It is said that I need to use `pdebuild` to build `source package`, but `pdebuild` doesn't resolve build dependencies. How can I build this package, so it can be finally uploaded? I don't want to install dependencies manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is that you don't.  `pbuilder` takes the source package and builds binaries.  It also can take the source code without a source package built and create the binaries that you would either host yourself or add to your own debian repository systems to host on your own.

That's not what you need for a PPA.

---

What you want to do, and what I strongly recommend, is that you follow traditional packaging procedures, and run `debuild -S` on the code, with the directory for the package there, containing the source code, the `debian/` folder, and everything else.

Then, after you've built the source package by `debuild -S`, you can then upload the created `.changes` file in one directory above the source directory to the PPA via `dput`.  (this step is referred to [on Launchpad's PPA Uploading help docs](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA/Uploading)).

You can in theory use `pdebuilder` to keep your system clean and build inside a chroot, but read on for my statements on this, as to why it failed previously for you.

---

Per the comments, you have correctly identified that debhelper is unable to find the `autoreconf` plugin.

Also as I said in my comments on this answer, `pbuilder` and `pdebuilder` are both not smart enough to determine the debhelper dependencies.

To solve your issue so that your stuff can build, you will have to manually use `pbuilder` or `pdebuilder` to login to the chroot.  Then, you will have to manually install `dh-autoreconf` into the chroot, usually with `apt-get install dh-autoreconf` after you've logged into the chroot.

Once you've done that, and saved the state of the chroot, you should be able to `pbuilder` or `pdebuilder` your package.

<sub>(However, I prefer traditionally working with packages, and I don't care if my build system is entirely clean or not, all I really build are source packages, and the debhelper plugins aren't going to clutter my system that badly)</sub>

Comment: I need `pbuilder` to make clean builds without installing anything on my system. If I just execute `debuild -S`, it fails with error message with unsatisfied dependencies. `pbuilder` had `pdebuild` command, so I thought it is used to build source packages with tools from chroot.

Comment: @techtonik That may be the case, however, for your chroot you'll have to install the specific debhelper packages anyways.  What's the specific errors you got?  (Unsatisfied deps during `debuild -S` indicates that you've got a special package that requires additional debhelper stuff, and usually requiring some things to be pre-built and uploaded for the builders to work with it, and neither `pdebuilder` nor `pbuilder` won't be able to automatically handle that, as a case in point, your attempts.)

Comment: I wish I knew that before starting http://askubuntu.com/questions/395584/how-to-build-a-newer-version-of-a-package-than-is-available-for-my-stable-releas The error log is at http://pastebin.ca/2519158 and it seems that I need this `dh-autoreconf`. I really hoped that `pbuilder` is the tool not only to run chroot, but also to resolve dependencies.

Comment: @techtonik ultimately, you *can* login to your chroot and force it to install `dh-autoreconf` but the chroot is the same as the standard `debuild -S` to that extent, if it has certain debhelper dependencies those have to be installed either by yourself to your system OR installed manually into the chroot.  Ultimately, while `pdebuilder` and `pbuilder` are smart, they aren't smart enough to determine what debhelper dependencies that need to be installed (they're smart to read the build-deps lines, in debian/control, but that doesn't dictate the debhelper dependencies.)

Comment: (out of space)  Ultimately, what `pbuilder` and `pdebuilder` do, as far as I can tell, is run the `debuild` or `debuild -S` inside the chroot with all the build deps, but that's pretty identical to me doing `debuild` (or `debuild -S` after debhelper stuff is installed) after installing the build-deps myself.  You have to read through the logs either way to figure out WHY your stuff failed, but ultimately, the end result is the same either way, you still need to install debhelper dependencies by hand beforehand, so the source package has all the stuff in it that it needs to build.

Comment: @techtonik also, keep in mind I maintain the `nginx` team's PPAs, I keep that pretty up to date except when I forget, and I have to adapt to these kinds of things all the time, I apologize for missing your first question on this issue, however I'm glad I could at least catch you on this one to give you some help.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. The answer that `pbuilder can not build source packages by automatically fetching dependencies for them` is good. I guess it is impossible to provide prooflink.

Comment: @techtonik not really, but, the issue here is that debhelper stuff is a little harder to "detect" because before pbuilder or sbuild or anything even *looks* at the build dependencies for the package itself, it tries with what it has to build the source package.  That's where it can explode, and that's why packaging isn't as simple as we'd like :/

Comment: Is the bug with inability to detect packages required to build the source described anywhere for reference? Yes, another level of indirection, but it makes tools much more intuitive for users.

Comment: @techtonik I don't know, I don't track bugs for packaging softwares.

Answer (score 2):

`pbuilder` is used to build binary packages from a source package. PPAs also build binary packages from source packages. Simply `dput` the `source.changes` file that you created when you also created the `<package>_<version>.dsc` file.

One of the main points in using `pbuilder` is to locally mimic the clean chroot environment that is used to build the binary packages both in the official archives and in PPAs.